# Button help: Quote Account Name not transferring to New Contract record Account Name field

Tags: account, quote

So, I have a situation...

I am trying to create a button on the Quote object that will transfer, by URL, field data to a Contract record. I am having an issue with the Account Name transferring.

1.) The Quote Account Name field (lookup to account object) does not seem to have an id to reference in the URL. Quotes are created directly from a related list on the Opportunity.

Bottom line is I need the Quote Account Name to transfer to the Contract Account Name field.

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Shannon

```
/800/e?
CF00N3000000B8JH6={!Quote.Name}&
CF00NS0000001SGhG={!Opportunity.Id}&
ctrc7‌​={!Account.Id}&
00N3000000B9WLE={!Quote.Total_Contract_Value__c}&
00N3000000B9WLJ={!‌​Quote.Annual_Contract_Value__c}&
ctrc40={!Quote.Contract_Term_months__c}&
ctrc25stree‌​t={!Quote.BillingStreet}&
ctrc25city={!Quote.BillingCity}&
ctrc25state={!Quote.Bill‌​ingState}&
ctrc25zip={!Quote.BillingPostalCode}&
ctrc25country={!Quote.BillingCount‌​ry}&
retURL={!Quote.Id}ote.BillingCity}&
```

Results:

```
/800/e?
CF00N3000000B8JH6=Test+Quote&
CF00NS0000001SGhG=&
ctrc7=&
00N3000000B9WLE=%2‌​418%2C995.00&
00N3000000B9WLJ=%2418%2C995.00&
ctrc40=12&
ctrc25street=123+Anyplace+Rd&
c‌​trc25city=Anwhere&
ctrc25state=PA+-+Pennsylvania&
ctrc25zip=19999&
ctrc25country=U‌​S&
retURL=0Q0S0000000Dp75
```

Comment: Can you share the URL you were currently trying to use?

Comment: /800/e?CF00N3000000B8JH6={!Quote.Name}&CF00NS0000001SGhG={!Opportunity.Id}&ctrc7={!Account.Id}&00N3000000B9WLE={!Quote.Total_Contract_Value__c}&00N3000000B9WLJ={!Quote.Annual_Contract_Value__c}&ctrc40={!Quote.Contract_Term_months__c}&ctrc25street={!Quote.BillingStreet}&ctrc25city={!Quote.BillingCity}&ctrc25state={!Quote.BillingState}&ctrc25zip={!Quote.BillingPostalCode}&ctrc25country={!Quote.BillingCountry}&retURL={!Quote.Id}

Comment: Here are the results when button is clicked: /800/e?CF00N3000000B8JH6=Test+Quote&CF00NS0000001SGhG=&ctrc7=&00N3000000B9WLE=%2418%2C995.00&00N3000000B9WLJ=%2418%2C995.00&ctrc40=12&ctrc25street=113+Pulte+Rd&ctrc25city=Lancaster&ctrc25state=PA+-+Pennsylvania&ctrc25zip=17601&ctrc25country=US&retURL=0Q0S0000000Dp75

Comment: Please update your question with this info in a readable format.

Comment: Not sure what you need me to change? It won't let me post in a stacked format?

Comment: Click on edit at the bottom left of your post to add your comments above with the URLs to your original post so they're easily readable by everyone.

Comment: Edited the question for you

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `accid={!Opportunity.AccountId}` vs. ctrc7‌​={!Account.Id}

1. The account field on the Quote is really just a reference to the Opportunity Account field so you need to refer to the source field, `{!Opportunity.AccountId}`. See [Quotes Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=quotes_fields.htm&language=en_US)
2. `accid` is the parameter in the Salesforce standard URL, you can see this by using the standard "New" contract button from the Account's contract related list.

Comment: It did not work. The Contract is being created from the Quote object not the account object.

Comment: @ShannonSF What is the resulting URL after that change?

Comment: /800/e?CF00N3000000B8JH6={!Quote.Name}& 
CF00NS0000001SGhG={!Opportunity.Name}& 
accid={!Opportunity.AccountId}& 
00N3000000B9WLE={!Quote.Total_Contract_Value__c}& 
00N3000000B9WLJ={!Quote.Annual_Contract_Value__c}& 
ctrc40={!Quote.Contract_Term_months__c}& 
ctrc25street={!Quote.BillingStreet}& 
ctrc25city={!Quote.BillingCity}& 
ctrc25state={!Quote.BillingState}& 
ctrc25zip={!Quote.BillingPostalCode}& 
ctrc25country={!Quote.BillingCountry}& 
retURL={!Quote.Id}

Comment: @ShannonSF I mean the results after the button click?

Comment: /800/e?CF00N3000000B8JH6=Test+Quote&CF00NS0000001SGhG=&accid=&00N3000000B9WLE=%2418%2C995.00&00N3000000B9WLJ=%2418%2C995.00&ctrc40=12&ctrc25street=123+Anyplace+Rd&ctrc25city=Anywhere&ctrc25state=PA+-+Pennsylvania&ctrc25zip=19999&ctrc25country=US&retURL=0Q0S0000000Dp75

Comment: @ShannonSF try taking a step back and remove all other parameters just leaving the accid parameter, does it work then? Also noticed "CF00NS0000001SGhG={!Opportunity.Name}" is not populating in your url either, sometimes it helps to look at one parameter at a  time to pinpoint the issue. If "CF00NS0000001SGhG={!Opportunity.Name}" is also a lookup field you will need to handle that special as well.

Comment: @ShannonSF were you able to get this working?